# Can't Dismiss View controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to dismiss a View Controller that has been presented as a modal .overCurrentContext.

The controller is presented like so

```
let vc= UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I call `dismiss` inside the vc controller that has appeared it does nothing.

To give more detail about the parent ViewController, it is a ViewController inside a NavigationController and it is third on the NavigationController's VC stack.

Comment: If it is inside a navigationController, you should dismiss navigation controller.

Comment: The presented VC isn’t inside a Nav, the VC it’s presented from is.

Comment: Try to call ```navController.popViewController(animated: true)```

Comment: Hi Amini, I would but the presented VC is not in a Nav so that won’t help.

Comment: Hmm your controllerA is presenting controllerB. ControllerA have to dismiss controllerB?!

Comment: What's the method for dismissing VC B from VC A?

Answer (score 0):

So the actual solution was very obscure.

I was using a Pod called FloatingPanelController that was causing some issues with dismissing my entire view stack intermittently.

In order to resolve it I modified an extension in the Pod

```
public extension UIViewController {
@objc func fp_original_dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    // Implementation will be replaced by IMP of self.dismiss(animated:completion:)
}
@objc func fp_dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    // Call dismiss(animated:completion:) to a content view controller
    if let fpc = parent as? FloatingPanelController {
        if fpc.presentingViewController != nil {
            self.fp_original_dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
        } else {
            fpc.removePanelFromParent(animated: flag, completion: completion)
        }
        return
    }
    // Call dismiss(animated:completion:) to FloatingPanelController directly
    if let fpc = self as? FloatingPanelController {
        if fpc.presentingViewController != nil {
            self.fp_original_dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
        } else {
            fpc.removePanelFromParent(animated: flag, completion: completion)
        }
        return
    }

    // For other view controllers
    self.fp_original_dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
}
```

In particular I removed the last line:

> ```
>     self.fp_original_dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
> ```

This is what caused the issue. I had no idea that this method was actually overriding the entire dismiss method. Once I re-inserted that line the issue was resolved.

This is likely very little use to anyone else!